# CUDA - determine number of banks in shared memory

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict

Shared memory is "striped" into banks.  This leads to the whole issue of bank conflicts, as we all know.

**Question:**
But how can you determine how *many* banks ("stripes") exist in shared memory?

(Poking around NVIDIA "devtalk" forums, it seems that per-block shared memory is "striped" into 16 banks.  But how do we know this?  The threads suggesting this are a few years old.  Have things changed?  Is it fixed on *all* NVIDIA CUDA-capable cards?  Is there a way to determine this from the runtime API (I don't see it there, e.g. under `cudaDeviceProp`)?   Is there a manual way to determine it at runtime?)

Comment: [This post](http://beyond3d.com/showthread.php?t=58047) says Fermi is 32 banks.  Have you tried looking in the CUDA programming Guide?  That's where the poster says he got this information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @RobertHarvey says, it's documented.  The programming guide indicates 16 banks for [compute capability 1.x](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-1-x), and 32 banks for [compute capability 2.x](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-2-x) and [3.x](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-3-0).  You can thus make any decisions based on the compute capability (major version) returned in device properties.

The general link to the cuda on-line documentation is contained in the [info link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) for the cuda tag.